# Javascript canvas slides when using sprite sheet animation

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to animate using a sprite sheet. However, when changing directions in player movement, the animation seems to slide through the sprite sheet to the animation instead of jumping directly to the sprite I want to use.

Here is my render function:

```
 function renderPlayer(me, player) {
   const { x, y, momentum } = player;
   const canvasX = canvas.width / 2 + x - me.x;
   const canvasY = canvas.height / 2 + y - me.y;

   context.save();
   context.translate(canvasX, canvasY);

   context.drawImage(
     getAsset('sasuke_sheet.png'),
     0,
     PLAYER_HEIGHT*momentum,
     PLAYER_WIDTH,
     PLAYER_HEIGHT,
     -PLAYER_WIDTH,
     -PLAYER_HEIGHT,
     PLAYER_WIDTH*2,
     PLAYER_HEIGHT*2,
   );
   context.restore();
}
```

Here are the values I am setting momentum equal to:

```
if(this.keys[0]) {
  this.momentum = 3;
  this.y -= dt * this.speed;
}
if(this.keys[1]) {
  this.momentum = 1;
  this.x -= dt * this.speed;
}
if(this.keys[2]) {
  this.momentum = 0;
  this.y += dt * this.speed;
}
if(this.keys[3]) {
  this.momentum = 2;
  this.x += dt * this.speed;
}
```

[sprite sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xUR9.png)

Comment: Could you describe what "sliding" means? After looking at your code, I think the issue is in either `this.speed`, `dt`, or `me.x/y`. Could you explain what these variables are?

Comment: Yea, so the as the PLAYER_WIDTH*momentum changes it is moving across the sprite sheet. However, the change from position 1 on the sprite sheet to position 2 on the sprite sheet seems to include snapshots of the sprite sheet in between those values. So you can visible see the player sprite sheet moving from position 1 to 2 when it should be instant.

Comment: Hmm... I don't see `PLAYER_WIDTH*momentum` in your code. Is there a separate render function for the columns?

Comment: It may help: https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/1455701-creer-un-mini-rpg-en-javascript-avec-canvas/1456460-les-personnages  it's in French but you can still translate the page